# How to create windows task scheduler from asp.net core 1.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm working with an ASP.NET MVC CORE 1.0 application. I'm trying to create a windows job scheduler from my .net core application. I have a console application which will perform the database operation. I want this console application to run every night at 11:59 PM. So I'm trying to create a Windows Task Scheduler and map this console application. I want to create this task using c# coding and not directly using Task Scheduler wizard.

I researched online and found few sample codes in which they are using this namespace Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler. But this namespace doesn't support with ASP.NET CORE 1.0.

Please someone help me to create task scheduler using .net core. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The task scheduler exposes a WMI interface to manipulate scheduled tasks, which you can invoke via `System.Management`.

You can find documentation on the scheduler at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394601(v=vs.85).aspx

You may also want to look at libraries like Hangfire which can be used in ASP.Net to schedule tasks at fixed times or regular intervals programatically without the scheduler.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me try to use Hangfire and update you.